# Sticky sidebar overlaps to the footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

I have Created custom sticky sidebar for ADS, it works but there is an issue. when I scroll it to the bottom, it overlaps on the footer. pls check.  - http://screencast.com/t/oEjcrbocB05C

```js
var stickySidebar = $('.sticky');

if (stickySidebar.length > 0) { 
  var stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height(),
      sidebarTop = stickySidebar.offset().top;
}

// on scroll move the sidebar
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if (stickySidebar.length > 0) { 
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            
    if (sidebarTop < scrollTop) {
      stickySidebar.css('top', scrollTop - sidebarTop);

      // stop the sticky sidebar at the footer to avoid overlapping
      var sidebarBottom = stickySidebar.offset().top + stickyHeight,
          stickyStop = $('.main-content').offset().top + $('.main-content').height();
      if (stickyStop < sidebarBottom) {
        var stopPosition = $('.main-content').height() - stickyHeight;
        stickySidebar.css('top', stopPosition);
      }
    }
    else {
      stickySidebar.css('top', '0');
    } 
  }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
  if (stickySidebar.length > 0) { 
    stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height();
  }
});
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: relative;
  top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check for site url is - http://www.test2.guru99.com/java-tutorial.html

Please Help Me !

Comment: your html is missing to make a usefull snippet

Answer (score 2):

Modify your following CSS

```
#rt-footer-surround {
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

To this, Add `position:relative` and `z-index:1`

```
#rt-footer-surround {
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```